# i7 7700 CPU power supply Watts

Tags: windows-10, power-supply, intel-core-i7

[image]

Can you tell me the power supply Watts for above configured PC? At this moment I have 350 W. Is that fine or?

**Note:** This is a software development PC and I'll not use this as gaming or any graphic design use cases.

Comment: DIY.....https://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator

Comment: You should also bear in mind that a 350 W PSU from a reputable company will safely supply 350 W. A very cheap PSU might not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It depends what you also have in the computer.** The most important being a graphics card, they can consume great amounts of power while on heavy loads.

But if you're not getting a graphics card, and relying on the CPU for graphics output, I personally think you'd be just fine with 350 watts. There is a lot of factors that play into that determination. But your 7700 isn't exactly a high end CPU that consumes crazy amounts of power.

As a general rule with any PC build in the last 10 years. I always get at least 500 watts of power for non-graphic card builds. For gamer computer builds 600-750 watts depending on the graphics card.

The reason is because the cost of a 350 to 500 watt power supply are generally the same, there is always a 500 watt power supply from a reputable company on sale that would cost the same was a 350 watt. So why not get something a little bigger.

Comment: Will, you recommend `Cool Master` or Termaltake? https://www.coolermaster.com/catalog/power-supplies/#!/ or https://www.thermaltake.com/products/power-supply.html?psu_wattage=94

Comment: brands are mostly irrelevant, just look at reviews aka failure rates. Product recommendations are considered off-topic.